# Azure VPN : Can ping server / FQDN but can not access network folder

Tags: vpn, network-shares, azure

I am able to connect to Azure VPN successfully, I can ping by IP address and host name, but when I open file explorer it hangs until "network path can not be found"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my first thought is you have a Network Security Group applied to one of the virtual networks, or the host nic, that needs to be configured to allow the SMB traffic

Comment: @FrankThomas : I Dont have any NSG's applied that will block anyone on Azure's end. I have multiple end users setup using the same system but this user does not work correctly. They can ping the IP and DNS name but when it comes to the shares it wont work.